# stripping a string using awk

Tags: awk

**input string**

```
prashant@prashant:~/Desktop$ xyz /123/ {print } abc.txt
```

after using awk command to strip on above input string I should get below

**output string**

```
xyz /123/ {print } abc.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F'$' '{print $2}' <<<"$str"
```

or if you don't want a space from the beginning try:

```
awk -F'xyz' '{print FS $2}' <<<"$str"
```

where the input string is stored in `str` variable as following:

```
str="prashant@prashant:~/Desktop$ xyz /123/ {print } abc.txt"
```

#### Explanation;

- The `-F'$'` defines the **F**ield **S**eparator to `$`
- The `print $2` prints the second filed `$2` with `$` as field separator between them.
- The `FS` in second command will prints the entry of **F**ield **S**eparator which is defined to `xyz`.

Comment: Also I want to know getting the required output using regular expression substitution.ie using like awk '{sub(/prashant/\@prashant/\:\~/\/Desktop\/$/,"");print}' abc.txt.   I am using this command but getting regular expression error

Comment: @prashantbj Glad it worked. For that try `awk '{sub(/prashant\@prashant\:\~\/Desktop\$ /,"");print}' <<<"$str"` and don't forget please [mark the answer as accepted](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer). thanks